# Admin New Order: Autofocus on Search a product

Tags: filters, hooks, order

I am creating a new order on backend and I want the Search for a product to be auto-focused when the form is loaded.

[image]

I've tried adding `autofocus` to the select field but it doesn't work. What's the proper hook/filter to use for this?
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Is this a custom modal you are using or a plugin? Include as much info as possible with your question including the code in question and what you have tried so far.

Comment: If there isn't an HTML way of doing this then you'll need a small bit of JavaScript to set the focus. Presumably there's already script on the page to open the lightbox that you can hook into.

Comment: @Abhik This is default woocommerce behavior so it is not a custom modal.

Comment: @Rup This is the default behavior so I'm not sure which hook is being used. Can you please help me out with figuring out the hook. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a Backbone modal, wc-modal-add-products, defined in [html-order-items.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.3.0/includes/admin/meta-boxes/views/html-order-items.php#L378) and triggered by [meta-boxes-order.js](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.3.0/assets/js/admin/meta-boxes-order.js#L558).

You say you've marked the field autofocus. [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40343088/243245) proposed adding an onRender handler to the modal that finds autofocus and selects it:

```js
$(this.el).find(':input[autofocus]').focus();
```

I don't know where the best place to put this is, but if you find the WCBackboneModal code you'll see [the render hook](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.3.0/assets/js/admin/backbone-modal.js#L79) ends by triggering a DOM event:

```js
$( document.body ).trigger( 'wc_backbone_modal_loaded', this._target );
```

I'd hook that event and use the code from SO, e.g. with jQuery (untested)

```
$( document.body ).on( 'wc_backbone_modal_loaded', function( event, el ) {
    $(el).find(':input[autofocus]').focus();
});
```

or if you're happy to edit the original WooCommerce scripts you can just add it to the render method there. (Note that by editing this or the template you're risking losing your changes when the plugin updates.)

However as this is a useful UI improvement to a built-in dialog I'd raise this with WooCoommerce as a feature request.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll test it in a few hours and get back to you